# How can i compare IEnumerable<List> with IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, list, listview, model-view-controller, ienumerable

I have two objects ,one object has list of values generated on UI and other holds the list which it fetches from database.

I want to compare both objects and if there are matching values then I want to pick the id of that value which is fetched by the object already to a variable.

And assign that Id to a new variable

Can anyone help me with this?

```
List<ListItem> commonMatch = errorDetailsList.Where(x => string.Equals(x.Value, 
     errorMessages.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

tried this but it always return me count = 0
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of `x.Value` for a few iterations, and `errorMessages`?

Comment: please, add sample content of both `errorDetailsList` and `errorMessages` and your desired result, so that people can write some code, test it and help you with your problem

Comment: The Other object is getting values from Database.

Comment: @AzharAmin You should be able to stick a debug breakpoint on that line and see what the values are.

Comment: i tried but it just returns null

Comment: Is `errorMessages` a collection of strings? Maybe you want `errorDetailsList.Where(x => errorMessages.Contains(x.Value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();`?

Comment: Maybe `null` is the issue. `Where` over a null collection will return zero items. Perhaps you need to cache the database result using a terminal call; i.e. `errorDetailsList.ToList().Where(...)`

Comment: Also if `errorMessages` is a collection of some sort, then calling `.ToString()` on it will just return the class name of the collection, rather than the items it contains. It's hard to see what you're doing without seeing how those things are declared and what data types they are.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thank you so much, that solved my problem, i got desired list but now i want to pick ids from that list and assign to integer variable, how can i used append with "," separations

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that has one matching element. I assume you need something like this, if I understood correctly:

```
    var errorMessages = new List<string>{"a", "b", "c"};
    
    var errorDetailsList = new List<ListItem>{
        new ListItem{Value = "b"},
        new ListItem{Value = "d"},
        new ListItem{Value = "e"},
    };
    
    List<ListItem> commonMatch = errorDetailsList.Where(listItem => errorMessages.Any(msg => msg.Equals(listItem.Value))).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(commonMatch.Count());
```